# Is it possible to celebrate a holiday twice by flying from one point on Earth to another?

Tags: flight-planning, time

It recently came to my attention that the different time zones on Earth could allow for a person to celebrate holidays such as New Years twice by flying from one point to another.

Is it possible to fly quickly enough to celebrate a holiday twice?

Comment: Related, although closed since it's about travel: [Are there any airlines that fly a route that has an arrival time earlier than its departure time?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57500/14897) / Trivia: Concorde flew fast enough that on westbound flights the rising sun, well, sat back down :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appears to be more appropriate for Travel SE.

Comment: @ymb1 Only if Concorde could fly now, I really wish to experience the supersonic speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any airlines that fly a route that has an arrival time earlier than its departure time?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/are-there-any-airlines-that-fly-a-route-that-has-an-arrival-time-earlier-than-it)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. As I right this, it is half past midnight at London, Heathrow. It is half past eight at New York Kennedy. And, it is half past five at Los Angeles. If it were not Daylight Savings Time, it would be half past seven in New York. On New Years Eve, you would have between 4 and 5 hours to celebrate in London, fly and land, before you started celebrating again In New York. Hardly any time for even a celebratory drink (as a passenger) and kiss. I have come very close to landing before I took off  when traveling from the US to the Asia. So far, I have never made it. I’ve always missed it by an hour or three.

It would be easier to celebrate New Years in somewhere like Lubbock, TX (Central Time, USA), then flying to Roswell or Clovis, NM (Mountain Time, USA).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of flights that depart Japan/East Asia after midnight and arrive in the US before midnight on the previous day.

Or there's NZ40, departing Auckland NZ at 0955 on, say, January 1, and arrives in Tahiti at 1555 on December 31. You could party, watch the new year fireworks, sleep, fly and arrive early enough to do it all again.